# Using display inline-block CSS in cfdocument

Tags: css, coldfusion, pdf-generation, coldfusion-9, cfdocument

The HTML/CSS below works in recent browsers, but not in CF9's cfdocument. Anyone with ideas?
I would like to use the inline-block property in cfdocument, if I can.  Or perhaps there is an alternative to render similar results?

**WHAT DO I KNOW?**
I am aware that CF's cfdocument supports a limited set of CSS properties (CSS1/CSS2). The CF documentation says it supports the **["display" CSS property](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/coldfusion_9_cfmlref.pdf)**.  However, it doesn't identify what values are supported.  I have included the Expected Output and some Example Code.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT** (See image below)
[image: IMG]

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" pagetype="letter">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>CSS Demo: Display Property (block, inline, inline-block)</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">

<style>
.container { margin-left: 2em; width: 35em; border: none; }
div { margin: 1em 0; border: solid 1px red; }
p { margin: 1em 0; border: dotted 2px blue; }
div#one p { display: block; width: 6em; text-align: center; }
div#two p { display: inline; width: 6em; text-align: center; }
div#three p { display: inline-block; width: 6em; text-align: center; }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div id="one">
        <strong>TEST 1: block</strong>  This text is within block-level level element (DIV).   
        <p>Here's a block-level paragraph (P).</p>  
        Here's some additional text still inside a block-level elment.
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <strong>TEST 2: inline</strong>  This text is within block-level level element (DIV).  
        <p>Here's an inline paragraph (P).</p>  
        Here's some additional text still inside a block-level element.
    </div>
    <div id="three">
        <strong>TEST 3: inline-block</strong> This text is within block-level level element (DIV).  
        <p>Here's an inline-block paragraph (P).</p>    
        Here's some additional text still inside a block-level element.
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: what format you need to use in cfdocument? did you try with format=pdf?

Comment: Oops!  I updated the Example Code above.  The first line should have included the <cfdocument format="pdf"...>.  Thanks @shemy.

Comment: `cfdocument` in CF9 only supports the following CSS1 `display` values: `inline | block | none`. `display: inline-block` was added in CSS2 and isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

You may try float instead display : [follow link](http://jsfiddle.net/richapandey/pvXQa/1/)

```
.container { margin-left: 2em; width: 35em; border: none; }
div { margin: 1em 0; border: solid 1px red; }
p { margin: 1em 0; border: dotted 2px blue; }
div#one p { float: right; width: 6em; text-align: center; }
div#two p { float: right; width: 6em; text-align: center; }
div#three p { float:right; width: 6em; text-align: center; }
.clear {clear:both; border:0px}
```